# Limit "Find References" in Eclipse to only references from my code

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on writing plugins for a large software application with 100+ imports.  Find References works great, but sometimes returns a few thousand results, though usually I'm only interested in finding references within my own code.  I can easily remove the references I'm not interested in from the search results, but is there a way to proactively limit the results?

Comment: An idea - in the long run at least - would be to use Mylyn, which might be helpful in such scenarios. Although I am not sure if it also applies to the references-search.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Search dialog, in the `Java Search` tab, you can select what kind of references you want, and where to search.
You can limit your searches to the "Sources" only and ignore "Required projects", "JRE Libraries" or "Application Libraries"

Comment: Wish there was a way to limit only to sources when right click on a method or class then References > Project, because opening a dialog is not as efficient.

Answer (score 3):

By default the reference finder (Ctrl+Shift+G) searches the whole workspace. If you rightclick on a method there is an option "Working Sets..." under "References". I guess this is what you are looking for. There you can define precisely which resources you want to consider.

You can set up a custom shortcut for this:

Preferences -> General -> Keys -> Search for "References in Working Set". Now set your custom shortcut and set "When" to "In Windows"

Comment: Thanks!  But all in all, I think I prefer the Java Search version that mhussein posted above, since I don't tend to use Working Sets.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but unfortunately for me none of this worked perfectly. @moeTi - i reached the same conclusion that you offered, but for me eclipse always asks me to choose a working set - i.e. it doesnt remember my previous choice. Any clue ?