# Eclipse: "Find All References" ignore target directory

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to limit the search for "Find all References" in Eclipse so that it ignores files in the target directory. This is not the same as the answer from this question: [Limit “Find References” in Eclipse to only references from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12597906/1762224). That answer only works for *text search*. I want all references to a particular variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Java project?

If the target folder is properly set as `Default output folder` in the project's properties > Java build path > Source you should be fine.

Source: just tested on Eclipse Indigo (I've tried `Ctrl+Shift+G` on both classes and variables); the search is limited to `src/main` and `src/test`.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to Maven build directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Go to Window->Customize Perspective. In **Command And Groups Availability** tab enable **Window Working Set** option if not enabled. Click **OK**
2. Go to Window->Working Sets->Edit. A dialog will pop up. Click **NEW** button
3. A dialog will pop up. Select **Resource**  option in that. Click **Next** Button
4. Click on **Select All** Button. Deselect the **target** folder. Enter the name for this working set say "Exclude target folder".
5. Open the source file in editor. Keep cursor on a variable. Right on that variable
6. Go References->Working set->Exclude target folder

By this you can also exclude some files along with folders. One drawback in this is that you have to manually deselect each and every files and folders to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click and select properties and then check the derived check-box. Done.

This works for the target directory and any other directories and files you want to exclude from searches and your normal workflow since the IDE will view these derived resources as resources that are not original data, and can be recreated from their source files.